# Wordpress $_POST value empty

Tags: php, html, wordpress, post

I'm working on a website at the moment using Wordpress. This is the first time I'm using it with PHP, and I had an issue I couldn't resolve alone.

Issue: My `$_POST` values are either not sending by my `<form>` or not received by my resume page. The value of my array is (0).

Here is the code :

Form page :

```
    <div class="page-paiement">

  <h1>Paiement en ligne</h1> 
   <form action="http://www.parisavecvousvisites.com/?page_id=1102&lang=fr" method="post" onsubmit="return confSubmit();" class="form-normal form-paiement"> 
    <label class="">Nom de l'entreprise :</label><input type="text" name="nom_entreprise" value="[insert_php] if(isset($_POST['nom_entreprise'])){ echo $_POST('nom_entreprise');}[/insert_php]" placeholder="Nom de l'entreprise" class="champs-paypal" required /> <br /> 
    <label class="">Nom du contact :</label><input type="text" name="nom_contact" value="[insert_php] if(isset($_POST['nom_contact'])){ echo $_POST('nom_contact');}[/insert_php]" placeholder="Nom du contact" class="champs-paypal" required /> <br /> 
    <label class="">Adresse mail :</label><input type="email" name="adresse_mail" value="[insert_php] if(isset($_POST['adresse_mail'])){ echo $_POST['adresse_mail'];}[/insert_php]" placeholder="adresse@domaine.fr" class="champs-paypal" required /> <br /> 
    <label class="">Numéro de téléphone :</label><input type="tel" name="numero_telephone" value="[insert_php] if(isset($_POST['numero_telephone'])){ echo $_POST['numero_telephone'];}[/insert_php]" placeholder="0XXXXXXXXX" class="champs-paypal" required /> <br /> 
    <label class="">Date de la visite :</label><input type="date" name="date_visite" value="[insert_php] if(isset($_POST['date_visite'])){ echo $_POST['date_visite'];}[/insert_php]" placeholder="JJ/MM/AAAA" class="champs-paypal" required /> <br /> 
    <label class="">Horaires de la visite :</label><div class="champs-horaires"><div class="horaire1"><div class="droite-horaire">De</div><input type="time" name="horaire_1" value="[insert_php] if(isset($_POST['horaire_1'])){ echo $_POST['horaire_1']};[/insert_php]" placeholder="00h00" required /></div><div class="horaire2"><div class="droite-horaire">à</div><input type="time" name="horaire_2" value="[insert_php] if(isset($_POST['horaire_2'])){ echo $_POST['horaire_2'];}[/insert_php]" placeholder="00h00" required /></div></div> <div class="clearboth" style="height: 23px;"></div> 
    <label class="">Nombre de visiteurs :</label><input type="number" name="nombre_visiteurs" value="[insert_php] if(isset($_POST['nombre_visiteurs'])){ echo $_POST['nombre_visiteurs'];}[/insert_php]" placeholder="1" class="champs-paypal" required /> <br /> 
    <label class="">Nombre de guides conférenciers :</label><input type="number" name="nombre_guides" value="[insert_php] if(isset($_POST['nombre_guides'])){ echo $_POST['nombre_guides'];}[/insert_php]" placeholder="1" class="champs-paypal" required /> <br /> 
    <label class="">Langue souhaitée :</label><input type="text" name="langue" value="[insert_php] if(isset($_POST['langue'])){ echo $_POST['langue'];}[/insert_php]" placeholder="FR" class="champs-paypal" required /><br /> 
    <label class="">Lieu<span class="texte-parentheses">(x)</span> :</label><input type="text" name="post_values[lieu]" value="[insert_php] if(isset($_POST['lieu'])) {echo $_POST['lieu'];}[/insert_php]" placeholder="Musée du Louvre" class="champs-paypal" required /> <br /> <label class="">Numéro de facture :</label><input type="number" name="numero_facture" value="[insert_php] if(isset($_POST['numero_facture'])){ echo $_POST['numero_facture'];}[/insert_php]" placeholder="XXXXXXXXXX" class="champs-paypal" required /> <br /> 
    <label class="">Montant à payer <span class="texte-parentheses">(TTC, en Euros)</span> :</label><input type="number" name="montant" value="[insert_php] if(isset($_POST['montant'])){ echo $_POST['montant'];}[/insert_php]" placeholder="00,00" class="champs-paypal" required /> 
    <div class="clearboth"></div> <input id="accept" type="checkbox"> J'accepte les <a href="http://www.parisavecvousvisites.com/?page_id=367" target="_blank">termes et conditions</a> générales de vente <br /><br /><br /> <div class="clearboth"></div> 
    <input type="submit" value="Valider mes informations" class="submit-resa"> 
   </form>

   </div>
```

Here is the resume where POST vales does not appear :

```
    <div class="page-paiement">

 <h1 class="text-center">Récapitulatif de votre commande</h1>

 [insert_php]

$os0 = $_POST['nom_entreprise'] . ' - ' . $_POST['nom_contact'] . ' - ' . $_POST['adresse_mail'] . ' - ' . $_POST['numero_telephone'];

$os1 = $_POST['date_visite'] . ' - De ' .  $_POST['horaire_1'] . ' à ' . $_POST['horaire_2'] . ' - ' . $_POST['nombre_visiteurs'] . ' - ' . $_POST['nombre_guides'] . ' - ' . $_POST['langue'] . ' - ' . $_POST['lieu'];

echo 'os 0 :'.$os0 . '<br />os 1 :' . $os1;

 [/insert_php]

[one_half padding="10px"]<div class="cadre-recapitulatif">
<b>Nom de l'entreprise :</b> [insert_php]echo $_POST['nom_entreprise']; [/insert_php]
<b>Nom du contact :</b> [insert_php]echo $_POST['nom_contact']; [/insert_php]
<b>Adresse mail :</b> [insert_php]echo $_POST['adresse_mail']; [/insert_php]
<b>Numéro de téléphone :</b> [insert_php]echo $_POST['numero_telephone']; [/insert_php]
<b>Date de la visite :</b> [insert_php]echo $_POST['date_visite']; [/insert_php]
<b>Horaires de la visite :</b> De [insert_php]echo $_POST['horaire_1']; [/insert_php] à [insert_php]echo $_POST['horaire_2']; [/insert_php]
<b>Nombre de visiteurs :</b> [insert_php]echo $_POST['nombre_visiteurs']; [/insert_php]
<b>Nombre de guides conférenciers :</b> [insert_php]echo $_POST['nombre_guides']; [/insert_php]
<b>Langue souhaitée :</b> [insert_php]echo $_POST['langue']; [/insert_php]
<b>Lieu(x) :</b> [insert_php]echo $_POST['lieu']; [/insert_php]
<b>Numéro de facture :</b> [insert_php]echo $_POST['numero_facture']; [/insert_php]
<b>Montant à payer (TTC) :</b> [insert_php]echo $_POST['montant']; [/insert_php]
```

Thank you and sorry for the tabulation.

Edit : Here is a screen of the resume page 
[Resume Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQJWg.png)

Comment: Possibly try changing the form to a get and see if the data is in the url as a get? If not then you know it's an issue with the form, if it is, then it's an issue at the end.

Comment: Ok man, i tried with a get form, and yeah I can watch my infos on my url, this is a problem with the second page.

Comment: Well i found what it was! The URL on from is redirected on my resume page, and I lose every POST data